# C++ error "expected initializer before <variablename>"

Tags: initializer

Good afternoon programmers,

I am very new to C++. I use eclipse and I have an assignment that asks me to calculate a future population when given constant birthrates, deathrates, immigrantrates, and the current population.

I get two errors.
1) On the line "float SECONDSINAYEAR;" I get the error "expected initializer before BIRTHRATEPERSEC"
2) On the line "CURRENTPOPULATION = 318933342;" I get the error "'futurepopulation' was not declared in this scope"

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

float main(void) {

//declaration of variables
float BIRTHRATEPERSEC;
float DEATHRATEPERSEC;
float IMMIGRANTRATEPERSEC;
float CURRENTPOPULATION;
float SECONDSINAYEAR;
float futurepopulation;

// Initialize constants
BIRTHRATEPERSEC = .5;
DEATHRATEPERSEC = -.1428571429;
IMMIGRANTRATEPERSEC = .04167;
CURRENTPOPULATION = 318933342;
SECONDSINAYEAR = 31536000;

// DO calculations
float futurepopulation = (CURRENTPOPULATION + (SECONDSINAYEAR * (BIRTHRATEPERSEC + DEATHRATEPERSEC + IMMIGRANTRATEPERSEC)));

//print output

cout << "The future population is " + futurepopulation <<endl;
return 0;

}
```

what should I do? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure but you are declaring futurepopulation twice. You don't need the "float" in front of it the second time. Also, main() usually returns an int so it's best to follow that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue is that your main should return an int, not a float.

You also declare float futurepopulation twice, once with your other variables and once with the summation.

Last problem is that in C++ you cannot add a number to a string that way, the correct syntax would be `cout << "The future population is " << futurepopulation <<endl;`

Comment: Thanks so much. This fixed everything!

Comment: No problem, please accept this answer if it fixed your issue.